# Can I use a mouse on BURG?

Tags: grub

Some users don't understand that you can only use the keyboard on BURG, and I was requested to enable the use of the mouse in it. Is there some way to enable the mouse in BURG?

Comment: Didn't you just answer your question?

Comment: no. see configuration options for BURG here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Burg and here for why the GRUB devs are uninterested in mouse support in GRUB2: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2011-10/msg00001.html

Comment: I already know how to configure BURG, but I tough that could be a different repository with mouse support or something like that. In the other, your second link might have game me some light in this answer:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2011-10/msg00009.html

Maybe I will be able to add mouse support to BURG by myself using this, but that's a plan for the future. Thanks anyway.